# How to do this in a WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: magento, wysiwyg

I need to make these two leaflets go side by side, instead of up and down. Anyone know how to do this?

Whenever it try to make them go side by side it flanks. I would appreciate any imput, or if there is anything like elementor for magento.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an updated version of the Magento 2 platform, you can enable the Page Builder for more dynamic content editing.

To enable Page Builder in Magento 2, go to Stores → Configuration → General → Content Management → Advanced Content Tools, then choose Yes for Enable Page Builder

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/page-builder/